# How to instal MinGW in openSUSE, Linux flavour?

Tags: mingw, opensuse

What is the procedure to install MinGW for [openSUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) and also send me the link where I could get a proper MinGW installation package.

Answer (score 5):

You can get openSUSE RPMs for MinGW here: [SUSE cross tool chain](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/CrossToolchain:/mingw/).

Answer (score -3):

MinGW is a minimal package of GCC. Linux uses the full GCC.

Comment: No, MinGW is not a minimal package of GCC. MinGW (or mingw-w64) provides a (GCC) compiler for Windows as well as a cross-compiler (to get Windows binaries on Linux or other OS).